# Exercise 1.11: Write a program that prompts the user for two integers. Print each number in the range specified by those two integers

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
int x1 = 0 , x2 = 0;
std::cout << "Enter two integers: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> x1 >> x2;
std::cout << " The range of the values entered is: " << std::endl; 
std::cout << x1 << std::endl;
while(x1<x2){
std::cout << ++x1 << std::endl;
        }
return 0;
}
```

/*First year in college, have C++ question. I'm using the primer book, here's my answer. It's a while statement exercise. The code works properly only when x1>x2.
So, it doesn't really work when x2>x1, and is it supposed to? This is my second day coding, it's a bit confusing. No answer in the back of the book (if that's even a thing in programming) and that's all. What's the answer supposed to look like?
*/

Edit: I found this on git hub:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int bg = 0, ed = 0;
  std::cout << "Enter the number of begin and end: ";
  std::cin >> bg >> ed;
  while (bg <= ed)
    std::cout << bg++ << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

/* Why does the  std::cout << bg++ << " ";   give us the list horizontally?
*I tried removing it and the list or range generated is given vertically, so why is this line able to give is the range horizontally?   */

Comment: The solution may be swapping `x2` and `x1` when `x2 > x1` or adding another branch to support the case. What is the expected output when, for example, the input is `10 5`?

Comment: Your answer is not a bad starting point. None of us can really know what is intended by the question though. Maybe you can always print the range low-high, or if the range comes in with `x1>x2` you can count down instead of up. But that should hopefully be clarified by the book or your teacher.

Comment: I would suggest search online how `while` loops work. Actually your program will never work when `x2 >= x1` because `while` loop will never be entered. Before doing the loop, find the lower and higher value of the two and loop from lower to higher.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code works when x1 < x2.

For x1 > x2, you could swap the integers before the while loop so that x1 < x2.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to swap `x1` and `x2` round if the former is greater than the latter (perhaps you always want to count from `x1` to `x2`), then use something like

```
std::cout << x1 << std::endl;
while (x1 != x2){
    x1 += (x1 < x2) * 2 - 1;
    std::cout << x1 << std::endl;
}
```

`(x1 < x2)` is either 0 or 1 (well actually `false` and `true` in C++, with an implicit conversion to an `int` type when multiplied by 2), so `(x1 < x2) * 2 - 1` is either -1 or 1.

Comment: Thanks, swapping seems to be the only way around this.

Comment: @somebody.exe: Or two versions of the loop. Depends on how simple you want this to be, or if the output of x1 > x2 should be different to x1 <= x2.